# How to decode an html encoded string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in asp.net C# web forms. I have a string with two spaces in it and have been HTML encoded and it looks like this: "My%20Driver%20Files.docx". I tried the following to decode it.

```
string decodedFileName = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(fileName);
string decodedFileName = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(fileName);
```

Where filename = "My%20Driver%20Files.docx". The resulting decodedFileName also has the same string value without replacing the "%20" with space.

Comment: That's because percent-encoding is a URL encoding scheme, not an HTML encoding scheme. No points for guessing what methods to use instead.

Comment: You are looking for UrlDecode i guess. Use WebUtility.UrlDecode("My%20Driver%20Files.docx");

Comment: Ha, I didn't know there is an URLDecode method. Thanks!